# How to pass Facebook Id from client to server securely

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a Facebook canvas app. I am using the JS SDK to authenticate the user on the browser-side and request various information via FB.api (e.g. name, friends, etc.).

I also want to persist some additional user information (not held on Facebook) to the database on my server by making an ajax call:

```
{ userFavouriteColour: "Red" }
```

To save this on the server and associate with the correct user, I need to know the Facebook uid and this presents a problem. How do I pass the uid from the client to the server.

**Option 1: Add uid to the ajax request**:

```
{ uid: "1234567890",
  userFavouriteColour: "Red" }
```

This is obviously no good. It would be trivial for anyone to make an ajax request to my web service using someone else's Facebook Id and change their favourite colour.

**Option 2: On the server, extract the uid from a cookie**:
Is this even possible? I have read that Facebook sets a cookie containing the uid and access token but do I have access to this cookie on my domain? More importantly, can I *securely* extract the uid form the cookie or is this open to spoofing just like option 1.

**Option 3: User server-side authentication on the server**:
I could use the server-side authentication to validate the user identity on my server. But will this work if I am already using client-side authentication on the browser? Will I end up with two different access tokens? I would like to make FB.api requests from the browser so I need the access token on the client (not just on the server).

This must be a very common scenario so I think I'm missing something fundamental. I have read a lot of the Facebook documentation (various authentication flows, access tokens, signed_request, etc.) and many posts on SO, but I still don't understand how client-side authentication and server-side authentication play nicely together.

**In short, I want to know the user's identity on the server but still make requests to the Facebook api from the client browser?**

(I am using ASP.NET and the Facebook C# SDK on the server)

**EDIT**: Added bounty. I was hoping to get a more deifnitive, official recommendation on how to handle this situation, or even an example. As said, I have already read a lot of the official FB docs on authentication flows but I still can't find anything definitive on how client-side and server-side authentication work together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:**
The easiest way I can think of is to include the accessToken in JS and pass it with the ajax call.

**Option 2:**
Using the same as option 1, but instead of sending just the accessToken, send the signedRequest.

On the server side you can decode it using (`TryParseSignedRequest` method) which will give you the `UserID` :-)

Note: `signedRequest` is encrypted with the application Secret. **you are the only one who should know it, so you are safe on that end.**

Disclaimer:

I have no coding experience in C#, but a little search in google gave me this:

[Facebook C# SDK for ASP.NET](http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/)

[Making AJAX Requests with the Facebook C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/ajax-requests)

Comment: If I pass the accessToken via ajax, is there a way to extract the Facebook userId from the token on my server without making a request to Facebook? And is this secure against spoofing? I don't want to make an FB api request from my server so I want to extract the user's Id based on information passed by the client.

Comment: well, FB.getLoginStatus (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) in the Javacript returns more the access token but also the user id, so you can send it to the server side...

Comment: Thanks for the link - that explains how to get the userId on the client. Maybe I'm not explaining myself very clearly. If I pass that userId to my server then it will be open to spoofing. How do I get the userId on the server in a secure manner?

Comment: Ahhhh... that makes more sense. I didn't realise I have access to the signed-request from the client, I thought I only have the access token. I will try this and see if I it works. Many thanks.

Comment: The "signed_request" can be decoded by anyone since it's base64 encoded. It's composed with both the encoded data and a signature which you can then use to test along with the app secret key that the request was indeed sent by facebook (since suppose to be the only ones but you with the secret key). Check it out in the [signed request guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)

Comment: Tried this method and it works perfectly. This lets me use a standard SDK and keeps minimum load on my server since I don't make any server-side FB requests. Many thanks to all who contributed suggestions.

Comment: As long as you don't think that sending the signed request is secured.

Comment: I believe this is completely secure. The signed_request is signed with my app secret so it is tamper proof. It would not be possible for a hacker to spoof a fake user id in the signed request as they do not have my app secret and could not generate the correct hash. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I also looked through the source of the PHP SDK and this seems to be exactly how they do it as well. Since the PHP SDK is provided by Facebook, I'm presuming it is pretty much the "official" way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple actually.

When the user loads you app use the [server side authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/), get the access token and load the user data by issuing an api request from the server.
On the server side you'll have everything you need and it's sandboxed.

When the page renders for the user, using the [js sdk](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) get the user authentication data, you should be able to use [FB.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) since the user already went through the server side authentication.
Now on the client side you also have an access token which you can use to get the user data from the graph api.

The two tokens will be different, and will also have different expiration, but that should not be a problem, both token should work properly as you'd expect them to.
Since both sides have their own token and a way to make requests to the api, there's no need to send any fb data between them.

So the 3rd option you mentioned, to me, sounds the best, and it's really simple to implement that too.

---

## Edit

All facebook SDKs are just wrappers for http request since the entire fb api is made on http requests.
The SDKs just give you easy and shorter access to the data with out the need to build the url yourself (with all the different possible parameters), make the request and parse the response.

To be completely honest, I think that stop providing a way for the C# SDK to support server side authentication is a very bad decision.
What's the point in providing a SDK which does not implement the entire api?

The best answer to your question, from my experience, is to use both server and client side authentication, and since the C# SDK does not support it, my advice to you is to create your own SDK.
It's not complicated at all, I already implemented it for python and java (twice), and since you'll be developing it for your own needs it can be tailored for your exact needs, unlike a public SDK which should support all possible options.

---

## 2nd Edit

There's no need to create a completely new SDK, you can just "extend" the ones you're using and add the missing parts that you need, like sever side authentication support.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The docs for the c# sdk state (http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Glimpse-into-the-Future.aspx) "...Starting from v6, you will have to use the Facebook Javascript SDK to get the access token and pass it to the server using secure https connection...". So they seem to be advising against fetching the access token on the server. Your thoughts?

Comment: I can see your point, but I really want to avoid wrinting and maintaining my own SDK - that's the whole point of having an SDK in the first place. Facebook is continually changing their API's and I want to be free to focus on my app domain, not correcting for breaking changes from Facebook every couple of weeks.

Comment: As I wrote, you don't have to implement it from scratch, just implement the missing parts, for example the server side authentication support.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I've awarded the bounty to @Roni as his answer specifically addresses the issue described in the original question (securely passing a user id from the client to the server). Thank you for taking the time to make an alternative suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's language specific but using both server-side and client-side authentication does no harm.

You can work on option 2 but yes, that will be also vulnerable to spoofing.

Doing option 3, you will be having a single access token for that user session, so that would be the best choice according to me since you always have chance of spoofing when passing user information from client side.

Comment: Does that mean I would have two different access tokens, one for requests from client and one for requests from server? Or would the two access tokens be the same?

Comment: you will have same access token.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same question recently. It's option 2. Check [this post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/534/) from the Facebook blog.

To be honest I am not enough of a hacker to know if you could spoof the UID in the cookie, but this seems to be the 'official' way to do it.

EDIT: to the other question under option 2, yes, I believe you have to access this cookie on your domain.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but how excatly do I extract the userId? I presume I need to extract it form the accessToken since this is encrypted. The example in the link uses the PHP SDK. Since this is possible in PHP then I guess the information is stored in the accessToken, but I can't find anywhere that explains how to extract it using the C# SDK (or manually even)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the C# SDK, but you can have a look at how the PHP sdk works by looking at the source [here](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php) find `getUserFromAvailableData` on the page. 

You have to get the [`signed_request`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) and decode it using your app secret I think.

Sorry I can't speak with much clarity on this because I've largely been sticking the the PHP SDK which is well documented.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Looked through the source code and in PHP they're doing it exactly the way @Roni suggests. It seems I need to pull the user id from the signed request and not from the access token. Thanks for the help.