# facebook authentication using signed_request

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to build an web application that facebook authentication so that don't have to build my own. So after facebook authenticates them and provides me with their user_id, I can simply store this in their database.

Obviously, I'd like to protect my users from being spoofed purely by using their user_id. Here's what I came up with:

1. Instead of passing the user_id back and forth between the browser and my server, I'll pass the signed_request because this cannot be spoofed without knowing my app_secret
2. To protect this from being sniffed and re-used, I'll encapsulate my requests in SSL (HTTPS)
3. To prevent stale signed_requests from being used, I'll make sure the issued_at is relatively recent.

Is this part of what signed_request is meant for, or is there a more correct way to use facebook authentication?

Any obvious problems with my approach?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be simpler not to exchange that data between client/server, and just have the client authenticate itself and the server do it on it's own, that way each side has it's own token and get query the graph for info it needs.

Comment: Well I've been following [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login) approach because it seems that using the JavaScript SDK is the easiest way to do facebook authentication.

If the authentication is performed by the client, I would still need something to pass to the server a validated identity and I was wondering if signed_request is appropriate for this.

Were you suggesting using completely [Server-Side Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) or is there something here that I am missing?

Comment: Yes, I do suggest using the server side authentication, it's really not complicated and, I think, gives you more control over things since you have an authenticated user **before** you even sent back the html output to him. Check out [How to pass Facebook Id from client to server securely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738068/how-to-pass-facebook-id-from-client-to-server-securely).

Comment: I do like having that user on my server side without relying on the client to pass me his identity. I noticed that in the server-side flow, the access token is passed in the URL so it is exposed even over HTTPS. Does this mean I am more secure if the client-side requests to facebook are HTTPS and the tokens I'm passing back to my server are over HTTPS?

Comment: The code is passed in the url, the access token is in the response of a https request. It's secured enough.

Answer (score 0):

That is a sensible way of authenticating the user. I think you've covered all the possible ways of by-passing the authentication system so you shouldn't have a problem.

If you are attempting to make API calls, you should also use the `FB.getLoginStatus()` function to personalise the experience for users already logged into your application.