# Facebook JS SDK, unsecure to pass UserID from client?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Using the facebook js sdk, I shouldn't pass the userID from the client my server to find their account and log them in, correct?

I need to use the accessToken to get the userID from the facebook server and then use that to find their account? If I used the userId from the client, anyone could pass in an id and log in to any user?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out: [How to pass Facebook Id from client to server securely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738068/how-to-pass-facebook-id-from-client-to-server-securely)

Comment: @NitzanTomer Thanks but this doesn't really help as they say to use sever-side auth to do it securely on the server. My question is about passing info from client-side auth to the server securely.

Comment: That is the most secure form, not to pass it and to get it on the server side. If that's not possible in your case, then what's wrong with simply send it over https?

Comment: @NitzanTomer Do you mean send the accessToken and then ping the fb servers for the id like I said? If the user just sends the userID they could send anyones userID.

Comment: Wait wait wait, I think I completely misunderstood you. What is it that you're trying to do? It's not clear from your question

Answer (score 1):

Facebook JS SDK sets cookie `fbsr_<application id>`  for your domain that already contains user id, so it does not matter if you send it or not.

Cookie payload is web-safe base64 encoded JSON that contains:

```
{algorithm: "HMAC-SHA256", code: <OAuth code>, issued_at: <time stamp>, user_id: <user facebook id>}
```