# is Facebook js sdk Sufficient to authenticate users in my site?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

in my site i Login using facebook js sdk, ( I tried the example in facebook page), but how can i tell the server that this user is authenticated ?.
I tried using ajax to post to the server .
but this seems unsecure !.

**My question is the authentication process can be donr using only JS sdk ?**

If the authentication process cannot be done using Js ,
what about facebook c# sdk or other unofficial facebook c# sdk.

```
  FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
       // POST TO SERVER AND TELL HIM THAT THE USER IS AUTHENTICATED NOW
     });
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 });
```

Comment: You can use the C# facebook SDK or the Facebook Serverside flow. Once you authenticate the user use formsauthentication

Comment: I asked exactly the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738068/how-to-pass-facebook-id-from-client-to-server-securely

Comment: can I now why downvoting the question ? !!

Answer (score 0):

The JS SDK can set a cookie on login, that you can read out server-side. If you do another call to /me there, then you can be relatively sure everything’s OK.